# Como configurar envio de email no Laravel dentro do cron?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3, cron

Apos a criação do cron(código abaixo) é feito uma varredura no banco atras de dados alterados. Tenho de enviar um e-mail com estes dados. 
Como posso fazer isso ???

**Codigo do cron:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class envioEmailBIcron extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'envioEmailBI:cron';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command Email';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
       //Pegar os dados no banco
        $sql = ' select * from payments as P, receipts as R ';
        $sql .= ' where P.created_at < CURRENT_DATE AND P.updated_at < CURRENT_DATE ';
        $sql .= ' AND R.created_at < CURRENT_DATE AND R.updated_at < CURRENT_DATE';

        //pega os dados no banco
        $query = \DB::select($sql);

       // executando as funções de envio de e-mail
       $this->info('Example Cron comando rodando com êxito');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para criar um e-mail com dados vindo do banco de dados ou qualquer fonte que alimente, faça o seguinte:

Digite na linha de comando:

```
php artisan make:mail ExampleCronSend
```

isso criará uma classe de configuração de e-mail com esse layout:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ExampleCronSend extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $dados;

    public function __construct($dados)
    {
        $this->dados = $dados;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('ExampleEmail')
                    ->to('email@recebe.com')
                    ->with(['dados' => $this->dados]);
    }
}
```

agora vai configurar uma pagina para o layout desse e-mail, um exemplo simples, crie dentro da pasta `resources/views` um pagina com o nome de `ExampleEmail.blade.php`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel - Resultados</title>
    </head>
    <body>    
    @foreach($dados as $r)
        <p>{{$r->description}}</p>
    @endforeach
    </body>
</html>
```

isso fornece um layout agradável que ainda pode ser melhorado.

Volte ao arquivo de `Command` e adicione essa chamada

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use DB;
use App\Mail\ExampleCronSend;

class ExampleCron extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'example:cron';
    protected $description = 'Example Cron Minutes';
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function handle()
    {

        $dados = DB::table('example')->get();

        Mail::send(new ExampleCronSend($dados));

        $this->info('E-mail enviado com sucesso ...');

    }
}
```

para testar digite:

```
php artisan example:cron
```

e se o processo tiver ***Ok*** recebe a seguinte mensagem:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esta aparecendo o erro:  [InvalidArgumentException]          
  Please provide a valid cache path.

Comment: @alexjosesilva depende da onde está aparecendo isso.

Comment: erro já foi corrigido com o comando: php artisan view:clear

Comment: agora o erro é outro: [ErrorException]                                                             
  Undefined property: stdClass::$description (View: /var/www/html/api-finance  
  ira/resources/views/corpoEmail.blade.php)

Comment: corrigir o erro no corpo do email: r->description não existe no array vindo do banco.

Comment: Troquei pelos dado r->id, r->creat_at

Comment: Novo erro:  [Swift_TransportException]                                                   
  Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Auth  
  entication required                                                          
  "

Comment: O último erro é de configuração do e-mail @alexjosesilva só falta isso... procure configurar isso corretamente

Comment: fiz uma pergunta so pra isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249824/erro-laravel-ao-enviar-email