# Erro: Laravel ao Enviar email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, cron

Ao tentar enviar email no laravel
Recebo essa mensagem de erro:

> [Swift_TransportException]
>   Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1
>   Authentication required"

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD= xxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**codigo EmailCron.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class EmailCron extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    private $dados;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($dados)
    {
        $this->dados = $dados;

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('corpoEmail')
                    ->to('xxxx@gmail.com')
                    ->with(['dados' => $this->dados]);

    }
}
```

**config/mail.php**

```
<?php

return [


    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.org'),

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    'from' => [
        'address' => 'XXX@gmail.com',
        'name' => 'DEV',
    ],

    'encryption' => env('ssl', 'tls'),

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
];?>
```

Comment: Como está seu arquivo  `config/mail.php`?

Comment: acabei de editar a pergunta com o mail.php

Comment: Sempre quando tenho esse problema, testo mudar `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` para `ssl` ou deixo vazio. Tente isso.

Comment: O erro persiste!

Comment: Cara, na moral, eu acho que seria legal você usar um http://mailtrap.io da vida pra testar emails, já que está em ambiente de desenvolvimento...

Comment: Tem que liberar no Gmail que o email não tenha tantas restrições, aqui no site já tem resposta para isso se eu não me engano.

Comment: Como faco isso? Editei a pergunta com os valores referentes ao email do mail

Comment: exemplo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-uOYk1AJpJ0

Comment: explicação ideal: https://learninglaravel.net/learn-to-send-emails-using-gmail-and-sendgrid-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu uso a versão 5.4 do `laravel` e passei pelo mesmo problema, configurei no gmail, com o hotmail, até o um e-mail comporativo que tenho, e nada fazia esse erro sumir, até que reparei na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#introduction):

> Driver Prerequisites
>   The API based drivers such as Mailgun and SparkPost are often simpler and faster than SMTP servers. If possible, you should use one of these drivers. All of the API drivers require the Guzzle HTTP library, which may be installed via the Composer package manager:

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Fiz conforme documentação e passou a funcionar aqui, acredito que esteja passando pelo mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1):

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Depois vc tem que ir no seu gmail e abilitar para aplicativos de terceiro consiga fazer esse envio.

Então entrem em [Login e Segurança](https://myaccount.google.com/security) e lá no final ira ver algo tipo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Devido as restrições do gmail cooporativo fui obrigado a utilizar minha conta pessoa do gmail e habilitar o acesso da minha aplicação para enviar email.

Em todo caso o código esta funcional enviando emails a cada ciclo de 24 horas como esta configurado no cron

**Respondo a pergunta:** Habilitar no gmail a autorização para envio de email. Geralmente o usuario do gmail recebe um email solicitando o bloqueio ou autorização